# c# Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons on form

Tags: c#, events, forms, button

Hi
Is there any way to find out if the close button (x button on form) was clicked. However without involving FormClosing and FormClosed events ?

Comment: Why without those events?

Comment: Why you don't want to use this Events?

Answer (score 0):

Without those Events? That's a tough one...no, I don't think so.

I mean, you hook yourself into the message pump of the form to figure out if those actions were invoked, but seems like a little overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PreProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.preprocessmessage.aspx) to see the message on its' way to your form.